# ASP.Net Core logging file not written in Linux environment

Tags: linux, asp.net-core, serilog, kestrel

I have an ASP.Net Core (.Net Core 1.1.1) application,
which using built-in logger and `Serilog.Extensions.Logging.File` for writing the log to file, it works well on my macOS development environment but CentOS environment.

The appsetting json:

```
"Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "PathFormat": "Logs/log-{Date}.log",
    "RetainedFileCountLimit": 7,
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
    }
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory) {
        loggerFactory
            .AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
            .AddFile(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"))
            .AddDebug();
```

The `Logs` directory not exists, I have check following:

- application folder owner is `centos`
- application services `User` is `centos`, same as folder owner
- logs is available on `journalctl`
- no error message

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have an appSettings.prod.json as an example that could be overwriting the logging node to have a higher logging level? You might need to set the Environment variables on the CentOS machine.

Comment: No higher level config file. Finally, I figure out that absolute path is working fine, so I created a folder on /var/log and `chown` to centos and point the log path to that folder.